# Cannot import matplotlib backend while using geoviews

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, maps, geoviews

I'm trying to run the examples from the Geoviews homepage (https://geoviews.org/index.html).
However, I can't use the matplotlib backend to plot surfaces.
I keep receiving this error:

> WARNING:param.notebook_extension: Holoviews matplotlib extension could
> not be imported, it raised the following exception:
> ImportError('cannot import name 'rc_params_from_file' from
> 'matplotlib' (unknown location)') WARNING:param.notebook_extension:
> matplotlib backend hook <function _load_mpl at 0x00000224D63544C8>
> failed with following exception: No module named 'matplotlib.ticker

I have already tried reinstalling matplotlib, geoviews, and holoviews.

I'm using running the code using Jupyter Notebooks in Windows 10.
Any ideas?

Comment: could you check the kernel using? is that the one that you installed matplotlib in?

Comment: I have installed Anaconda and I'm running python 3.7.9.
Not sure if that answers your question...

Comment: I had a ton of trouble with Anaconda recently. I have  tried to reinstall using the newest version, but it wouldn't work properly (navigator and spider wouldn't open). What solved the problem was uninstalling everything, reinstalling Anaconda using an older version, and then updating everything.